# if condition scenario not working properly

Tags: shell-script

```
a=59
b=4
if [ $a = 59 ];
then
a=0
b=b+1
echo $a
echo $b
```

I want the output of a to be "0" and b to be incremented by 1 when a is equal to 59

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a closing `fi` statement.  Try like this:

```
a=59
b=4
if [ "$a" -eq 59 ]; then
    a=0
    b=$((b + 1))
fi
echo "$a"
echo "$b"
```

Comment: Thanks much its working... just a small info if i need to have else statement like this in the above scenario ..else a=a b=b, then how to do it , pls guide me

Comment: @VimalKumar, I've updated my answer with what I believe you are looking for.  I think it would be unnecessary to specify that `a="$a"` or `b="$b"` because it would be redundant.